# How to get phylogenetic tree from multiple genes?

Tags: sequence-alignment, phylogenetics, phylogeny, multiple-sequence-alignment

I constructed a phylogenetic tree using a gene (example - [secA](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P10408)). I had to gather the same gene sequence for all the required species from public database-NCBI and then constructed the tree after multiple sequence alignment. I used the MEGA X software.

I now want to build a single phylogenetic tree using concatenated multiple genes, around 20.

How do I go about it.
Do I,

1. Concatenate all gene sequences for each species and do a multiple alignment or
2. perform an alignment for each gene and finally concatenate the alignments to get the tree?

Could this be done using MEGA X?